# Native Base components not rendering on Expo Go but works fine on web

Tags: javascript, react-native, button, text, expo

I have a page in my application that is a form with Native Base Inputs and Buttons. When I check the page on the web, everything works and looks fine. However, when I launch it on Expo Go, only the first header, input, and title loads. The remaining buttons, inputs, and text below that do not load in.

This is my original code.

```
import { View, Text } from 'react-native';
import { Button, Input } from 'native-base';

const Control = () => {
  ...

  return (
      <View>
        <Text style={styles.header}>FOO</Text>
        <View style={styles.container}>
          <Input 
            w={200}
            placeholder="Device" 
            marginBottom={2}
            marginTop={2}
            onChangeText={selectDevice}
          />
          <Text style={styles.title}>BAR</Text>

          //EVERYTHING BELOW DOES NOT SHOW UP ON EXPO GO
          <Button 
            title="THIS DOESN"T LOAD"
            onPress={controlDevice}
            style={styles.button}
          >
            {telemetryState}
          </Button>
          
          <Text style={styles.title}>THIS DOESN'T LOAD</Text>
          <Button 
            title="THIS DOESN'T LOAD"
            onPress={controlLED}
            style={styles.button}
          >
            {THIS DOESN"T LOAD}
          </Button>
          <Text style={styles.title}>THIS DOESN"T LOAD</Text>
          <Input 
              w={200}
              placeholder="THIS DOESN'T LOAD" 
              marginBottom={1}
              onChangeText={handleChange}
          />
          <Button 
            title="THIS DOESN'T LOAD"
            onPress={controlLight}
            style={styles.button}
          >
            THIS DOESN'T LOAD
          </Button>
        </View>
      </View>
  );
}

export default Control;
```

I have tried to alter stuff and move things around. Instead of using the Text component from react-native, I have tried to use the Text component from native-native, but this didn't do anything.

I have found that, for some reason if I remove the titles, the buttons and inputs load in.

```
import { View, Text } from 'react-native';
import { Button, Input } from 'native-base';

const Control = () => {
  ...

  return (
      <View>
        <Text style={styles.header}>FOO</Text>
        <View style={styles.container}>
          <Input 
            w={200}
            placeholder="Device" 
            marginBottom={2}
            marginTop={2}
            onChangeText={selectDevice}
          />

          // <Text style={styles.title}>BAR</Text>
          <Button 
            title="THIS DOESN"T LOAD"
            onPress={controlDevice}
            style={styles.button}
          >
            {telemetryState}
          </Button>
          
          // <Text style={styles.title}>THIS DOESN'T LOAD</Text>
          <Button 
            title="THIS DOESN'T LOAD"
            onPress={controlLED}
            style={styles.button}
          >
            {THIS DOESN"T LOAD}
          </Button>

          // <Text style={styles.title}>THIS DOESN"T LOAD</Text>
          <Input 
              w={200}
              placeholder="THIS DOESN'T LOAD" 
              marginBottom={1}
              onChangeText={handleChange}
          />
          <Button 
            title="THIS DOESN'T LOAD"
            onPress={controlLight}
            style={styles.button}
          >
            THIS DOESN'T LOAD
          </Button>
        </View>
      </View>
  );
}

export default Control;
```

Does anyone know how to fix this issue?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think there may be a problem in your stylesheet or something like this. I am just guessing.

**Remove this:**

```
height: 100, // For example maybe it is a const height.
overflow: "scroll"
```

Comment: Yea, I had my title style with a height of 100%. Getting rid of that fixed my issue.